# Java.lang.NoClassDefError when application is run

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp

I am using a external java API and added it to my plugin by updating the pom.
The API JAR gets updated under Referenced Libraries of my plugin. When I use the external API classes, imports gets updated properly as well as the methods works fine.

To build the end state I maintain a separate plugin. In it's pom we would have mentioned all the plugins that required for the end state to be built.

When I work with the end state Application(created using product) I get "Java.lang.NoClassDefError" in the place where I have used the external API's Class.

I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Can any one let me know how to fix this issue.

IDE I am using is eclipse.

Comment: Show the whole stacktrace please.

Comment: You need to include the API JAR in your classpath *at runtime*

Comment: are you sure you are not only including the api only? Have you included the implementation jar? Sometimes plugins separated their api (interface only) and their implementation

Comment: Does you generated manifest file have that import ?